# Why isn't standard Gibbs free energy always zero?

Tags: thermodynamics, equilibrium, free-energy

I read in my textbook that one of the standard conditions we should use when calculating the standard Gibbs free energy is having a concentration of 1 M of all the reagents and the products in the reaction. But if you use the formula $G = -RT\ln K_\mathrm e$ and you use 1 M to calculate it, you would always get zero.

So that means 1 M would be the initial concentration of reagents and products before reaching equilibrium?

Comment: See this https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Gibbs_free_energy_of_formation It says 1 mole of products only, not reactants.

Answer (score 5):

$\Delta G = \Delta G^\circ - RT \ln(K)$

It isn't directly $G$, but formula for change in free energy. Also, in standard conditions $\Delta G = \Delta G^\circ$, so it isn't necessarily 0.

[Relevant reading on a website](http://chemed.chem.purdue.edu/genchem/topicreview/bp/ch21/gibbs.php)

Comment: That link helped a lot!! Thank you so much ((:

Comment: @EwelinMachado If his helped a lot, you can press the V button next to his answer.